# Is it possible to include same email in two groups in mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

Is it possible to include same email address in two groups in MailChimp?
Here is a hypothetical use case.
List contains users from a college.
One group is for students.
One group is for teachers.
But some teachers are also students. so their email address should be in both groups.
We tried importing same address to both groups via CSV, but got error.

"Yikes! There were no emails added to your list.
2 emails were already subscribed or had unsubscribed and cannot be re-added."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible for a subscriber to be in multiple groups. You'll want to use the auto-update flag on your import to update the settings of a subscriber who's already on your list. See [this page](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/update-subscriber-information) for details on that import setting.